# How to change electron app icon without electron-packager?

Tags: javascript, electron

I want to create a simple desktop application on Linux(Ubuntu) and set an icon for my application. For the first time i changed it simply by icon property:

```
win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600, icon: `file://${__dirname}/icon.ico`});
```

After that i changed its icon file, But it didn't change to new icon on Ubuntu Launcher! Its icon is the same icon which i set for the first time and it doesn't change even i remove its icon file.
Can anybody help me?

Comment: i think this is a ubuntu matter [see](http://askubuntu.com/questions/80627/how-can-i-change-the-icon-of-an-application-in-the-unity-launcher)

Comment: Thank you @mrkovec for your answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contrary to my impression this issue was an Ubuntu matter. To solve this problem go to `~/.local/share/applications` then you'll see all config files with `.desktop` extension, now simply remove intended config file to reset application icon on Ubuntu Launcher.